# Python not opening the file i selected

Tags: python

Code:

```
os.startfile("C:\finished.py")
```

Return:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\**x0cinished**.py'
```

Expectation: take C:\finished.py

What could be causing python to change my input like this?

Comment: It's interpreting `\f` as an escaped character, like `\n`.  Use the `os.path` module or raw strings `r'C:\finished.py'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'\f'` is a special character (see [Table of escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences)). You should make it a habit to use `r` (raw strings) when working with hard-coded paths:

`os.startfile(r"C:\finished.py")`

Comment: I agree, even though I would prefer to say "use os.path" package and create the path name without being platform specific then....

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the "\" character. Write "C:\\finished.py" in your startfile statement.